# Cancel Edit View Realm.io Database

Tags: cocoa, realm

I want to create an edit view for an existing object model in a Realm.io database. The view controller has a save button which should persist the changes and a cancel button which should discard the changes.

I can not modify a `RLMObject` outside of a write transaction, so what is the recommended method of temporarily modifying a `RLMObject` enabling me to discard the changes later if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass your realm object in to your edit view controller as an in-memory object to do your editing. Like so:

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[StringObject createInDefaultRealmWithObject:@[@"a"]];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];

StringObject *obj = [[StringObject alloc] initWithObject:[[StringObject allObjects] firstObject]];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(obj.stringCol, @"a");
obj.stringCol = @"b"; // not in a write transaction
XCTAssertEqualObjects(obj.stringCol, @"b");
```

If the user presses "Save", you can then call `createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithObject:` and pass in your in-memory object, which will then pass in all the values and update that object in Realm. Note that your object must have a primary key for this to work.

If the user presses "Cancel", you can just discard that in-memory object as if nothing happened.

Note that we intend to add transaction rollback functionality in the future, which will simplify this pattern.

Comment: I look forward to seeing transaction rollbacks.

Comment: @jpsim is this still the recommended way? Even if transaction rollbacks are here now, I still think using your method is the right way.

Comment: Now that rollbacks are enabled, they are the preferred way to cancel short-lived transactions. Long-lived transactions benefit more from the approach described in this answer, since writes block other writes in Realm. Keep in mind that writes don't block reads, and reads never block any other transaction.